# Как перезапустить завершенный поток заново

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Мне нужно перезапустить завершенный поток. Поток находится в состоянии (Stopped). Как ее перезапутить?

```
void Work1()
{
    while(!terminate) {

        Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(5));
    }
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, чего вы хотите. Вывести поток из Sleep'а? Завершить? Запустить новый? Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Дело в том что я завершаю поток присвоив terminate = true, но я хочу этот поток заново запустить не пересоздавая экземпляр потока. Возможно ли это?

Comment: Нет. Поток бежит только один раз, можно лишь создать новый поток после завершения старого.

Comment: @Мирлан Если поток уже остановлен (т.е. завершилась его функция основная) то его вроде уже нельзя возобновить, зато можно сделать вот что - обернуть тело функцицю потока в вечный цикл, в конце цикла просто поток в Sleep ставить как вы сделали выше, при этом через какую-то переменную подавать сигнал чтобы поток выходил из Sleep и шёл на очередную итерацию в самое начало, в итоге получится вечный поток который будет исполнять работу, ставиться в сон и вновь возобнавляться по команде.